# Linux-разделы и python-скрипт

Tags: python, linux

Как из python-скрипта узнать, на каких разделах хранятся каталоги **/var/lib/limited-apt/** и **/usr/** (**limited-apt** - это мой собственный каталог)? И как узнать свободное пространство на них (для меня также важно знать, это один и тот же раздел или разные)?

Comment: Попробуйте утилиту `findmnt` отсюда https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/mount-info-for-current-directory, ее вывод можно кастомизировать и использовать в скрипте на python

Comment: ну есть путь, есть mount есть du. в Чем проблема?

Comment: @Maggot, вы видимо не видели ничего более простого, чем конфигурация разделов на вашем компьютере. Окей, успехов!

Comment: @0andriy возможно

Comment: Ну смотря как вы хотите это сделать — переносимо или не очень, под systemd или под старые утилиты, с учётом bind и overlayfs или нет, ну и так далее. Тема богатая на исследования.

Comment: @StanislavTsepa, тогда причём тут Питон?

Comment: @0andriy ее было бы удобно использовать поскольку можно кастомизировать вывод, то есть не пришлось бы вручную парсить то что выводит du. Я имею ввиду, конечно, что вызывать эти утилиты надо через модуль subprocess

Comment: @0andriy ну а где предложения решения задачи человека который ничего сложнее как найти раздел видимо не делал ?

Comment: @Maggot Пусть вначале ответит на мой комментарий выше. Тогда и рекомендации смогут появится. Вы-то сами исследовали вопрос между своими двумя комментариями?

Comment: @0andriy да) я почитал Ваши, и понял что не надо тратить время на это )